# Smallest singular value of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, singular-values

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a matrix and $\sigma_n$ be its smallest singular value. Prove that
$$\sigma_n^2=\min_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^TA^TAx}{x^Tx}.$$
From [Proving that the norm of a Matrix is bigger or equal to it's smallest singular value multiplied by a vector.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330716/proving-that-the-norm-of-a-matrix-is-bigger-or-equal-to-its-smallest-singular-v), I know that $$\sigma_n^2\leq  \frac{x^TA^TAx}{x^Tx}\ \text{for all}\ x \neq 0.$$
How to prove that minimum is actually attained?

Comment: *"How to prove that minimum is actually attained?"* why don't you try $\mathbf x:= \mathbf u_n$  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
Given a symmetric matrix $M$, consider the scalar function
$$\mu(x) = x^TMx \quad\implies\quad \p{\mu}{x} = 2\,Mx$$
The objective function is a ratio of such functions, therefore
$$\eqalign{
\lambda &= \frac{x^TA^TAx}{x^Tx} \;\doteq\; \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \\ 
\p{\lambda}{x} &= 2\beta^{-1}(A^TAx-\lambda x) \\ 
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero yields an eigenvalue equation, whose solutions are the extrema of the objective
$$\eqalign{
A^TAx &= \lambda x \\ 
}$$
Since $(A^TA)$ is SPD, its eigenvalues and singular values coincide. So the minimum of the objective function corresponds to the smallest singular value.